# Google Apps Script - Sheet - Menu Trigger not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

So I am building a mailmerge tool, and it works fine.

Testing the trigger with a hard coded input works fine:

```
function test(){
  sendEmails("TEST MAILMERGE FROM DRAFT")
}
```

It also works fine if I prompt an input box (relevant section of the code shown).

```
function sendEmails(subjectLine,sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
  if (!subjectLine) {
    subjectLine = Browser.inputBox(
      "Mail Merge",
      "Type or copy/paste the subject line of the Gmail " +
        "draft message you would like to use:",
      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL
    );

    if (subjectLine === "cancel" || subjectLine == "") {
      // if no subject line finish up
      return;
    }
  }
```

However, trying to be smarty pants and have the menu dynamically populated with Subject lines like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  // get the UI for the Spreadsheet
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  
  // add the menu
  const menu = ui.createMenu("TEST"); 
  
  // get the drafts from Gmail
  let drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages(); 
  
  // for each draft, create a new menu item
  drafts.forEach((draft) => {
    // add the drafts to be triggered using the following: addItem(caption: string, functionName: string)
    menu
      .addItem(
        draft.getSubject().toString(),
        'sendEmails("' + draft.getSubject().toString() + '")'
      )
      .addToUi();
  });
}
```

However, this doesn't work. It comes up with the following error:

> Error Script function not found: sendEmails(TEST MAILMERGE FROM DRAFT)

Which to me looks like it should work. As the testing trigger that is hardcoded above works.
Am I being daft here? As far as I can see, this should work? But it's not.

When / if I get it working, I will put a check in to account for 'trash' drafts that don't have a subject. Just trying to get it to actually work for now though.

Answer (score 0):

### [Menu.addItem(caption, functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#additemcaption,-functionname)

**Parameters:**

- `caption`: The label for the menu item, with only the first word capitalized.
- `functionName`: The name of the function to invoke when the user selects the item. You can use functions from included libraries, such as Library.libFunction1.

`Menu.addItem()` expects a function name without arguments. It doesn't allow to pass arguments in the function.

---

### Workaround:

Based on my understanding, your goal is to have a different menu item that could send emails on each draft messages available in your email account.

You might want to consider using [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) or [Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) where in you can select your draft message subject that you want to pass as argument when you call your `sendEmails()` function. You can refer to the sample code as reference.

**Sample Code:**

(Code.gs)

```
function onOpen() {
  // get the UI for the Spreadsheet
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  
  // add the menu
  const menu = ui.createMenu("TEST")
    .addItem('Send Email', 'selectDraft') 
    .addToUi();

}

function selectDraft() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('draft');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Select Draft Message');
}

function getDraftSubject(){
    
  // get the drafts from Gmail
  let drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages(); 
  var subjects = [];
  // for each draft, create a new menu item
  drafts.forEach((draft) => {
    subjects.push(draft.getSubject().toString());
  });
  Logger.log(subjects);
  return subjects;
}

function sendEmails(subjectLine,sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {

  Logger.log(subjectLine);
}
```

(draft.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Select Draft Subject</h2>
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Draft Subject</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="subject" name="subject" required>
          <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form> 

  
  <script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(subj) {
      let select = document.getElementById("subject");
      subj.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = e;
        option.text = e;
        select.appendChild(option);
      });
  }).getDraftSubject();

  
  function handleFormSubmit() {
    
    var value = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    google.script.run.sendEmails(value);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }

</script>
</body>
```

**What it does?**

1. Create a custom menu that will show a dialog box based on the draft.html
2. In draft.html, We used [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) to call `getDraftSubject()` in our server side (apps script) which returned an array of draft message subjects. We then update the form's `select` class and add options based on each draft message subjects obtained.
3. When the form was submitted, it will call `handleFormSubmit()`, we get the selected draft message subject and pass that value using [google.script.run.myFunction(...) (any server-side function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function).

   `google.script.run.sendEmails(value);`

---

**Output:**

[image]

[image]